# Combining root and non-root event functions in R desolve

Tags: r, events, ode, desolve

I am using R and the desolve package to implement a model with events occuring at both specific times and events occuring when certain condtions are true (i.e. root events).

As some background code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869884/ode-multiple-roots-and-events-r) demonstrates using root events which trigger when a condition is met, whilst code [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-dynamic-models/2013q1/000160.html) demonstrates using multiple non-root events.

As would be expected if a root event is used the time step will not be a trigger and vice versa if a time trigger is used the root will not trigger.

I considered using a root that returns 0 when the model time matches the event time. I have implemented this below and it appears to function however my understanding is that when building models we should not assume that the model time will occur (indeed I understand this is the entire reason behind using events). Therefore I am unsure if this is good practice or if there is a better way to do this.

```
library("desolve")
yini <- c(temp = 18, heating_on = 1, eventoccurs = 0)

temp <- function(t,y, parms) {
  dy1 <- ifelse(y[2] == 1, 1.0, -0.5)
  dy2 <- 0
  dy3 <- 0
  list(c(dy1, dy2, dy3))
}
event_times <- c(1, 5, 20)
rootfunc <- function(t, y, parms) {
  time_in_event <- 1
  if(t %in% event_times){ time_in_event = 0}
  yroot <- c(y[1] - 18, y[1] - 20, time_in_event)
  return(yroot)
}

eventfunc <- function(t, y, parms) {
  time_in_event <- 1
  if(t %in% event_times){ time_in_event = 0}
  yroot <- c(y[1] - 18, y[1] - 20, time_in_event)
  whichroot <- which(abs(yroot) < 1e-6) # specify tolerance
  if(whichroot == 2) { y[2] <- 0 } else { y[2] <- 1 }
  if(whichroot == 3) { y[3] <- 1 } else { y[3] <- 0 }
  return(y)
}

times <- seq(from=0, to=20,by=0.1)
out <- lsode(times=times, y=yini, func = temp, parms = NULL, 
             rootfun = rootfunc, events = list(func=eventfunc, root = TRUE))
plot(out, lwd=2)
```

**Extension - co-occuring events**
I expected if this is the solution I may go on to have issues where multiple events occur at the same time but from experimenting it appears that providing the same paramters are not modified by multiple co-occuring events this is not an issue. I presume the correct way to handle these instances would be document the order of priority and, ideally, print/log a warning that it has occured (clearly for time triggered events a check could be made before the model is run but root triggers will only be discovered during the run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [deSolve: Can't understand how to early stop ode solver with root functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376807/desolve) I sketched the general idea of the root->action event mechanism. This means that `desolve` actively searches for a root if a sign change in one component of the root function is detected. As such the result of the root function should be a list of a continuous functions that change sign at the root. For the fixed times it should be a list of `t-event_time(k)`.

---

To avoid code duplication, and thus for higher flexibility, in `eventfunc` simply use `yroot=rootfunc(t,y,parms)`.